# How to reload state onTap in BottomNavigationBar Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I am using a `BottomNavigationBar` in Flutter for displaying posts in a feed.
I want to preserve the state of widgets in different Navigation sections, so I am using `IndexedStack`
But when the user the is on active Section of the Navigation and retaps the active icon, I want to reload the feed.

I am catching if the user is on same page and tapping the action icon using:

```
  onTap: (index) {
    if (_indexNumber==index) { //if the active page is same as tapped page
      setState(() {
        //I want to reload the state of the widget
      });
    } else {  //if active page and tapped page are different
      setState(() {
        _indexNumber = index;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should access the object that responsible for feed update from onTap handler. How do you send a network request for feed? For example, if you use bloc pattern then the answer is simple: use `BlocProvider.of<FeedBloc>(context).add(UpdateFeed());`

Comment: But that function is a class level local function, declared in some other class

Comment: can you access this class from onTap callback? If it's possible, provide more details - code of the class and update feed function, build function code with IndexedStack with children